# how to handle this kind of data

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-5.4, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using **laravel-5.4** in this project
with **"maatwebsite/excel"**

I'm planning to create a feature for my website where the I can upload an excel file then show the data of this file in my view

the form I used to upload and send my data to the back end

```
public function bundleaddstudent(Request $request)
{

   if($request->hasFile('excelstudent')){

          $File = $request->file('excelstudent');
              $path = $File->getRealPath();

      $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {

        })->toObject();


          return view('User.content.tobe_added_students')
          ->with('selection', $this->selection())
          ->with('Students', $data);

    }
  else
  {
    return view('User.content.Add_student')
        ->with('selection', $this->selection())
        ->with('Students', 'No Data')
        ->with('request', $request);
  }
}
```

now that the file that has been uploaded and has been handled in my controller for it to be converted as **data object** and was also been passed with the new view.

I now need to handle the passed data in my view **this is how I've done it**

```
 @isset($Students)
    @foreach ($Students as $key => $value)
      <tr>
          <td> {{$value}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
 @endisset
```

but sadly the output of this is like this

[image]

if I try to `{{ $value->dump() }}`

an error would occur saying ***Method dump does not exist.***

if I try to {{ $key }}

the output is an integer starting for 0 - 4 outputting it like

```
----------------------------
| studentID  | Firstname  |
----------------------------
|     1      |            |
|     2      |            |
|     3      |            |
|     4      |            |
```

> you get the Idea

I also tried `{{ $value->studentId }}` but it is showing me nothing

[image]

base on the Comment of @LrdArc that I should Try

```
@isset( $Students )
      {{  dd( $Students )  }}
@endisset
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
LaravelExcelReader {#353 ▼
  +excel: PHPExcel {#361 ▶}
  +reader: PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007 {#354 ▶}
  +file: "/tmp/phpu3zVBH"
  +columns: []
  +title: "phpu3zVBH"
  +ext: ""
  +encoding: false
  +format: "Excel2007"
  +parsed: RowCollection {#430 ▼
     #title: "Sheet1"
     #items: array:5 [▼
       0 => CellCollection {#495 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:9 [▼
             "studentid" => "15-2000332"
             "firstname" => "Dummy1"
             "lastname" => "Dummy1"
             "middlename" => "Dummy1"
             "course" => "Dummy1"
             "ay" => "Dummy1"
             "gender" => "Dummy1"
             "address" => "Dummy1"
             "contact" => "Dummy1"
        ]
      }
      1 => CellCollection {#496 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:9 [▼
           "studentid" => "15-2000333"
           "firstname" => "Dummy2"
           "lastname" => "Dummy2"
           "middlename" => "Dummy2"
           "course" => "Dummy2"
           "ay" => "Dummy2"
           "gender" => "Dummy2"
           "address" => "Dummy2"
           "contact" => "Dummy2"
        ]
       }
         2 => CellCollection {#515 ▶}
         3 => CellCollection {#514 ▶}
         4 => CellCollection {#513 ▶}
     ]
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
okay I've just tested it. Change toObject() into get() in your controller.

It's an object. Try something like this in your view:

```
@isset( $Students )
  @foreach ( $Students as $student )
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $student->studentID }}</td>
      <td>{{ $student->firstname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $student->lastname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $student->middlename }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
@endisset
```

Comment: try `dd( $Students );` what's the output?

Comment: @LrdArd I've **edit it to add** the output of `{{ dd( $Students ) }}`

Comment: @GroverReyes change `toObject` into `get()`

Comment: same result. `get()`